# Angular: rendering a lot of DOM Elements faster

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rendering

I work on a calendar application which is developed with Angular and I'm exposed to a rendering performance problem. I took a look to a lot of subjects about the rendering performance of the ngRepeat, I tried bindonce but I'm still stuck.

I created a plunker to show you my problem. http://plnkr.co/edit/UHVC5a?p=preview - it reproduces the logic of my application.

Let says it's a calendar with 5 rows (one per week) with 150 events per row (I know that's a big number but for someone very busy it's common).

As you can see, the rendering is very slow. Is it something that I can improve? Do you have any thoughts?

Thanks you very much.

Comment: Are you using 'track by' already? http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2556-Using-Track-By-With-ngRepeat-In-AngularJS-1-2.htm.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I use 'track by' already.

Comment: In the example you show you have 2250 events your adding to the page (450 per row and 5 rows).  Somewhere in the neighborhood of half your time is spent applying the `event` directive to all those elements.  My first thought is to try to scale back how many events you show on the first page- even just from a UX standpoint, that's a lot of info to put in front of someone

Comment: FYI...  If you only had 50 event elements displayed per week- so 250 for the whole month my measurements show you going from over 500ms render time to just over 100ms.  You could always show users some kind of filter to help get your 2250 events down to something more manageable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I notice that the template for each event uses a few bindings. A few suggestions:

- It might be worth investigating if using something like https://github.com/pasvaz/bindonce would speed it up.
- Or you could set the HTML of each element manually in the directive, rather than using bindings.
- There is an asynchronous function getColor in each directive use. Does this mean there will be 150*5 = 750 calls to the server? It might be worth re-thinking that architecture, as that is quite a lot, and likely to take time no-matter how fast the Angular becomes
- If those asynchronous calls are indeed necessary/don't each call the server, then you could only change the $scope variables in all the instances of the directives at once / or grouped, say by adding the promises to an array, periodically checking it to run some functions on the resolved ones, or using $q.all.